# Rancher - HTTPS cert issue - installing cattle docker container

Tags: linux, container, coreos

I am trying to add a new host to my Rancher environment (using v1.6.17). I add the public IP and hostname then copy & paste the Docker link to the other host. I'm getting CA certificate errors as it provided me with an HTTPS link. Something similar to this:

```
$ sudo docker run --rm --privileged \
   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
   -v /var/lib/rancher:/var/lib/rancher rancher/agent:v1.2.10 \
   https://IP:8080/v1/scripts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I set up a different environment previously and I got a HTTP link so I didn’t have this issue. Can you tell me how to use HTTP only for cattle installation?

Comment: Have you tried replacing https in the url with http?

Comment: https://forums.rancher.com/t/how-to-upgrade-rancher-agents-to-use-ssl/5138

Comment: Are you using self signed certs or a real SSL cert? - if self signed - https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.3/en/installing-rancher/installing-server/basic-ssl-config/#using-self-signed-certs-beta.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but it seems like I have found the answer online. 
Here:
https://3503bfe669f8-003837.vbulletin.net/forum/main-forum/372-v3-virtualbox-poc-cannot-connect-rancher-hosts